# cannot reuse variable in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am having some trouble with gitlab-ci. I have a maven project and I want to build the image with the version.

What I'm actually doing:

```
stages:
 - build_maven

test_build:
  stage: build_maven
  script:
    - export VERSION=$(mvn --non-recursive help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -v '\[.*')
    - docker build --build-arg VERSION=$VERSION --no-cache -t registry.gitlab.com/mycompany/myproject/service-mine:$VERSION .
    - docker pushregistry.gitlab.com/mycompany/myproject/service-mine:$VERSION .
  tags:
    - myserver
  only:
    - development
```

But version variable is not available. I also tried to put everything in a shell script but still the same the variable VERSION is empty.
Does someone have an idea ? Thanks

Comment: Closing parenthesis is missing from the mvn command.

Comment: thanks it was a copy paste issue

Answer (score 1):

This worked

```
export VERSION=`mvn --non-recursive help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep -v '\[.*'`
```